# Showing a Warning: Error in :: NA/NaN argument in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

For my shiny App, I am reading an hourly time series in CSV format. I want to find the annual maximum value for which I am using an R package extRemes. This has fun called blockmaxxer to find annual maximum with input data and blocks as years. When I select the CSV file, I am getting an NA/NaN argument error.
I want to find where the problem is.

```
library(shiny)
library(zoo)
library(extRemes)

Annual_max <- function(vect_table,yr){

  L = c(1,2,3,6,12,24,48)
  n = length(L)
  
  xx <- vect_table
  m = length(xx)
  D = matrix(0,m,n)
  E = matrix(0,m,n)
  
  yeardata <- unique(yr)
  NY <- length(yeardata)
  AM = data.frame(matrix(0,NY,n))
  
  for (i in 1:n) {
    D[,i] = rollapply(C,L[i], sum, fill=0, align="right" )
    E[,i] = D[,i]/L[i]
  }
  
  ##### To find annual Maximum
  for (j in 1:n) {
    datA <- as.matrix(data.frame(year=yr, y = dur[,j]))
    AM[,j] = blockmaxxer.matrix(datA[,2],blocks=datA[,1])
  }
  return(AM)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Choose observation precipitation CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      selectInput("HR1","Choose the column number of Hour 1", choices=c()),
      selectInput("HR24","Choose the column number of Hour 24", choices=c()),
      selectInput("Year", "Choose the Year column", choices=c())
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('pl')
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  inputdata <- reactive({
    infile = input$file
    if(is.null(infile))
      return(NULL)
    df <- read.csv(infile$datapath,header=input$header)
    updateSelectInput(session,"HR1",choices= colnames(df)) 
    updateSelectInput(session,"HR24",choices= colnames(df)) 
    updateSelectInput(session,"Year",choices= colnames(df))
    return(df)
  })
  ### Converting the hourly data to a vector format
  vectdata <- reactive({
    req(inputdata())
    dat <- inputdata()
    A <- t(as.matrix(dat[,input$HR1:input$HR24]))
    B = as.numeric(as.vector(A))
    replace(B,is.na(B),0)
  })
  
  AMP <-  reactive({
    req(inputdata())
    req(vectdata())
    df <- Annual_max(vectdata(),inputdata()input$Year)
    return(df)
  })
  
  output$pl <- renderPlot({
    req(AMP())
    plot(AMP())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The console is showing as given below.

```
Warning in `[.data.frame`(dat, , input$HR1:input$HR24) :
NAs introduced by coercion
Warning in `[.data.frame`(dat, , input$HR1:input$HR24) :
NAs introduced by coercion
Warning: Error in :: NA/NaN argument
  217: [.data.frame
  213: <reactive:vectdata> [D:/Work/Shiny/s1.R#62]
  211: .func
  208: contextFunc
  207: env$runWith
  200: ctx$run
  199: self$.updateValue
  197: vectdata
  190: <reactive:AMP> [D:/Work/Shiny/s1.R#68]
  188: .func
  185: contextFunc
  184: env$runWith
  177: ctx$run
  176: self$.updateValue
  174: AMP
  167: renderPlot [D:/Work/Shiny/s1.R#74]
  165: func
  125: drawPlot
  111: <reactive:plotObj>
   95: drawReactive
   82: renderFunc
   81: output$pl
    1: runApp
```

I am new at shiny, so any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Without your data / csv it is hard to help. When I look at this line `datA <- as.matrix(data.frame(year=yr, y = dur[,j]))` I wonder where `dur` comes from I can't find it in your code.

Comment: I made a mistake there dur is E. The App was working fine till I added the annual maximum part. I changed dur to E, still getting  NA/NaN argument error. As for my data - station code, year, month, day, hr1,hr2,....,hr24 is the columns. Its an hourly rainfall data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `A <- t(as.matrix(dat[,input$HR1:input$HR24]))` would work on dataframes. Try using `select` from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

A <- dat %>% select(all_of(input$HR1):all_of(input$HR24)) %>% t
```

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example to test this? You can remove all the code which is not required for this question. Provide data which can be easily copied ( Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) so instead of uploading the csv we can use this data and explain the expected behaviour.

Comment: I tried this but not getting the results. My annual maximum part is having some trouble. But your correction removes the NA formation from vectdata. But gives me a new warning. Can't subset columns that don't exist.

Comment: I had few more functions to add to this code, on a whim I coded all my steps and used your suggestion its working. Thanks a lot. I am actually very relieved I got my final result. I am still getting warnings, I just need to learn how to suppress it.